# Rate of acceptance of UK transit visas for Indians

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I’m planning to transit through LHR on my way to FRA(Frankfurt, Germany) from BOM(Mumbai, India). I’m in the process of applying for a DATV for transit through LHR.

I was reading multiple posts online regarding transit via LHR, and read that most transit visa applications are rejected. Is this true?

(Before someone asks, I’d like to mention that I’ve chosen this route over Lufthansa since I had quite a bit of Avios).

Edit: I’m planning to travel towards the end of May. My Schengen visa has been approved.

Comment: When are you planning to travel? I doubt that ‘most’ transit visas are rejected (people only tend to post about rejections, those receiving a visa have no reason to do so, after all).

Comment: Hi @Traveller, I’m planning to travel towards the end of May. My Schengen visa has been approved.

Answer (score 4):

In Q4 2019, the UK approved 825 transit visas and refused 92 from Indian nationals, an approval rate of 90%.

Statistics from UK government [managed migration datasets](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/managed-migration-datasets): [Entry clearance visas granted outside the UK](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/868220/entry-clearance-visa-outcomes-datasets-dec-2019.xlsx)